# Python urljoin does not join string properly if it starts with question mark

Tags: python-3.x

So:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
urljoin('https://abc.info', '?scurr=EUR&page=')
```

Result:

```
'https://abc.info?scurr=EUR&page='
```

Expected result:

```
'https://abc.info/?scurr=EUR&page='
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib` is doing the right thing. The trailing slash (or lack thereof) is significant and those are technically different routes. It is often the case that one would rewrite them and/or handle them as though they were the same for SEO reasons.

In your example, the trailing slash is important so add it to the base URL:

```
urljoin('https://abc.info/', '?scurr=EUR&page=')
```

gives us:

```
https://abc.info/?scurr=EUR&page=
```